# Term for optional module at a high school with compulsory pass

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, academia

What do you call an optional module/subject/class at a high school or university which is optional, but must be passed if chosen?

Comment: *Elective paper* or *Elective subject*. You'll be able to choose whatever you elective you want and you'll be given credits if you pass. If it is not mandatory, we call it *x credit course* where x is the number of credits allocated for that subject and you can take that subject for extra credits.

Answer (score 2):

It is usually known as an **elective subject/course/paper** in academia. It is a subject slot in which you are given a set of optional subjects, among which you are to select one. A degree course may have more than one elective.

Specifics like The number of electives per semester, whether the *n* electives are selected from a single set of *m* subjects or disjoint sets of subjects would be up to the regulations stipulated by the institution.

Comment: Does an elective subject always mean a subject with compulsory pass?

Comment: Yes, ... it does